# How can I remove a child or childs which provide certain conditions in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I could not find a way to remove object(s) from my database. I have sarched for like one days and when I tried to delete it deletes all objects from my taglist part of database.Here are my database tree and my code to delete the taglist object -M6QYGd-Hftv5NfS5KsI. However the codes I found and I wrote deletes the all taglist objects from database. Is there a way to delete the taglist objects whose name is "AHA" from database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asXKN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dNF5.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are new to stackOverflow. The best way to post your code is typing it in the question box itself and pressing ctrl+k by selecting the code part.

Anyway, Coming to your problem, you are creating an anonymous (temporary)query when you call

```
databaseReferenceTagList.orderByChild("name").equalTo("AHA")
```

A reference in the database(which has physical existence in the database) like  databaseReferenceTagList can be represented by a query because `DatabaseReference` is inherited from `Query`. Since it has physical existence it can be deleted. But every query need not have a reference(physial existence).

The query you designed consists of the references to the tags whose name is "AHA"(they physically exist). However there is no exclusive physical existence for a list of tags whose name is "AHA". It is just a part of a bigger list-taglist(which of course has a physical existence on the database).

So the bottom line is

- you can delete only those items which have a physical existence
- The items having physical existence are those which have references
- All queries need not have references. Only those which are DatabaseReference objects have a reference.

Now the big problem is even if a query does not have a reference, it has data and hence DataSnapShot. Its DataSnapshot's `getRef()` returns the reference of the nearest parent of the query which has a reference.

Therefore the (temporary)query you created returns the taglist reference when you call its datasnapshots' `getRef`.

And hence the whole taglist is removed on calling removeValue.

The solution is to call removeValue only on references you get from the datasnapshots of actual references.

In your case, we know that each tag has an actual existence and we can you that to call `removeValue`. Therefore instead of calling `removeValue` on dataSnapshot,

```
for(DataSnapshot d:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   d.getRef().removeValue();
}
```

This will individually delete each child(only one in this case) of the query and not the reference(which is faulty) itself.

Please feel free to comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I got it, my problem solved.